# how can take specific object screenshot in ios

Tags: ios

i am new developer on ios. i develop a normal where i use some button and screen background image. i can take screenshot with button and background. now i want to take screen shot specific object. can it possible in objective c

this is my code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
imageView.layer.zPosition = 14;
imageView.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Specific object? An image on the screen?

Comment: From the above I assume you are saying that the user can click on a button and it will take a screen shot of the page and background image and you were asking how to take a screen shot of a specific UI element?

Comment: it may be two or more UIImageView with bacground. -@ogixologist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes u can take screen shot of specific object as mentioned below:-

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(hiddenView.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0); //In this I have take screenshot of a hiddenView that I have added from IB with a background color anything( in this case it's orange). 
//Replace this hiddenView object with your object of whom you want to take screenshot.

[hiddenView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  //Similarly replace hiddenView here with your object.

UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 );
imgView.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:theImageData];  //I placed a UIImageView to check and place the screenshot into it as Image ,simply to cross check if I'm getting a right screenshot or not.
//So you could also remove this line after your have verified that your getting right screen shot.
```

Anything else then let me know.

Comment: i can not understand what is "hiddenView" and how can take snapshots of  specific object that means UIImageView?

Comment: hiddenView is a UIView which I had place in my demo so I passed bounds of that hiddenView(set it's background color to orange) and when I had the NSData as result so to cross check I placed a UIImageView along with Image using NSData. It worked. Also I have updated a bit of explanation in my post so give a look.

Comment: @Asaduzzaman your welcome and don't forget to tick it as answer :)